# Syntax error in MySQL CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I want to make a table in phpmyadmin and I am using SQL command for that

```
CREATE TABLE userdetail(    
detailid INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
address text,
phone varchar(13) NOT NULL,
email_id varchar(255),
userId int(20) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>       name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>       address text,
>       phone varchar(13) NOT ' at line 2

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY` and not just `PRIMARY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
 CREATE TABLE userdetail(    
    detailid INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    address text,
    phone varchar(13) NOT NULL,
    email_id varchar(255),
    userId int(20) NOT NULL,
    reg_date TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `KEY` after `PRIMARY`:

```
CREATE TABLE userdetail (    
    detailid INT(255) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    address text,
    phone varchar(13) NOT NULL,
    email_id varchar(255),
    userId int(20) NOT NULL,
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

Note that `int(255)` really doesn't make sense.  Are you familiar with the integer data types and what the value in parentheses means?  You can review the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote?  The answer looks correct.